# How to make flutter app load a specific route

Tags: flutter, routes

I have a Inshort like news app, whenever I send notifications I want app to show specific cards from scrollable cards. How are routes managed to navigate to the card when the user clicks a notification directly?

Comment: try firebase cloud messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: may be I asked little wrong. I sent firebase notification which should refer to a particular slide by calling route. So how to find such routes in existing package( I got package from others and I have not coded them )